# How to create predictable output with a Lazy<StackFrame>

Tags: c#, .net, logging, system.diagnostics, diagnostics

I'm working on some internal logging framework and for the sake of performance it seems a good idea to lazily get a `StackFrame`. I want to use this `StackFrame` to get the first method outside my logging framework.

My initial idea was this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void Caller()
    {
        NeedsToNowCaller();
    }

    public void NeedsToNowCaller()
    {
        Processor.GetName(() => new StackFrame(4));

        Really();
        Assert.AreEqual("Caller", Processor.stackFrame.Value.GetMethod().Name);
    }

    public void Really()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Caller",Processor.stackFrame.Value.GetMethod().Name);
    }
}

public static class Processor
{
    public static Lazy<StackFrame> stackFrame;

    public static void GetName(Func<StackFrame> stackFrameProvider)
    {
        stackFrame = new Lazy<StackFrame>(stackFrameProvider);
    }
}
```

But when you swap these lines:

```
    Really();
    Assert.AreEqual("Caller", Processor.stackFrame.Value.GetMethod().Name);
```

Results are unpredictable, since the call stack is changed. Is there anyway to get a hook to the local scope/frame through a closure, while retaining the laziness.

The only solution i can think of is stepping through the StackTrace, until i detect the first frame with a unknown method.

I really hope there's a better solution.

Comment: I have coded such a logger. All extra data are added automatically. There's no need for a `Lazy<StackFrame>`.

Comment: @Xaqron Why is there no need? Creating a StackFrame for every log message introduces overhead, since these properties are not always accessed.

Comment: @JJoos: Why log `StackFrame` when no `exception` occurred ? and if an `exception` occurred you already have the `StackFrame`

Comment: @Xaqron Because if an error occurs, it isn't always an exception. Also i want to know where the logging occurs.

Comment: @JJoos: If an error occurs you should throw `exception` and then handle it. That's why exceptions exist. About exception source, you are right, you need `StackFrame` and there's already one attached to your `exception`.

Comment: @Xaqron: So for example, my database server is down. I catch the exception generated by my orm. But i want to know which stackframe in *my* code makes the final call to the orm library. Should i then rethrow the exception to some intermediate layer? Or should i just log it where i catch the exception and get a new stackframe?

Comment: @JJos I am very confused.  In the assertion inside NeedsToNowCallers() and Really(), you are asserting the stackframe returning "caller" but they are actually called at two different scopes.  If one is returning "caller", the other should not.  BTW, you need to be aware that in release build, the compiler might choose to make some function inline.  The way that you hardcode stackframe(4) may work in debug build but not in release build.  I also don't understand why you need to have a static Lazy<> object.  Do you really want it to be static?

Comment: @harvey Your completely right and i'm searching a method to always get the caller method, when i need it. The inlining is a minor problem for me, since it would still give the same answer all the time, only one extra frame down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is much better, but instead of looking for an unknown method, it might be simpler to look for a different source class.   This is a bit rough, but would something like this work to give you the last frame before entering the logging class without having to maintain a list of "known" method names (assuming the logging method is not a static...)?

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    int index = 0;
    StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(index++);
    while (this.GetType().Name.Equals(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name))
    {
        frame = new StackFrame(index++);
    }
    //...
}
```